# How to disable MFA during sign-in in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using custom policy in Identity Framework in Azure AD B2C. I have SignUpOrSignin.xml and TrustFrameworkBase.xml to custom the policies. I have activated MFA during sign-up but it also activated on sign-in. How can turn-off it during sign-in ?

Comment: Which [custom policies](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) are you using?

Comment: SignUp_SignIn policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute the MFA step on sign-up but not execute it on sign-in by adding the `newUser` claim as a `ClaimsExist` pre-condition:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>newUser</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

The `newUser` claim is created during sign-up by one of the following technical profiles: **LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail**, **SelfAsserted-Social** or **AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId**. It won't exist during sign-in.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It works perfectly. Thank you Chris !